# How to control column/page breaks in multicols environment with nested lists?

Tags: lists, page-breaking, multicol, columns

I've a nested list within a multicolumn like this:

```
\begin{multicols}[2]
  \begin{list}
    \item main item1
      \begin{list}
        \item this is a very long item 
        \item this is a short item
      \end{list}
    \item main item2
      \begin{list}
        \item short item here
      \end{list}
    \item main item3
      \begin{list}
        \item this is a long item 
        \item this is a short item
      \end{list}
    \item ....
  \end{list}
\end{multicols}
```

However, it happens that the multicol package or LaTeX breaks the column or the page immediately after the first level `\item` and before the `\begin{list}`. This really looks bad. It also happens, that the `\item` is on the last line of a page and the nested list starts on the next page.

Does anyone know how that could be changed, so that there is no longer a column/page break at that not so nice position (without having to manually insert `\columnbreak` every time), cause the document is really long and auto-generated from a database.

Shortest possible example (but just a special case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{list}{}{}
        \item{Item 1}
        \begin{list}{}{}
            \item{Sub Item 1}
        \end{list}
    \end{list}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple `\nobreak` inserted before `\begin{list}`?

Comment: @Joseph Yes I tried that, but it did not help. It looks like `\nobreak` is ignored or there is a break inserted with each `\item`. So I also tried to add a `\nobreak` before the sublists items, but that also did not help.

Comment: I currently have a look at ltlist.dtx so that I understand what and especially why those things happen. Maybe I need to create a completely new list environment to achieve what I want to have?

Comment: As it looks like now it's a low-level LaTeX issue in regard to `\item`. `\nobreak` can't help as the penalty is permanent reset. The shortest possible example is shown with edit 1 in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inhibit that break by setting `\@beginparpenalty` in the inner list to 10000, as this penalty is inserted by each `\item` command (which start the LR mode); the second argument to `\begin{list}` contains commands to be executed at list start. Here's an example; without `\nobreaklist` the break happens in the way you describe.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\textheight=.5\textheight
\advance\textheight\baselineskip % just to show the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\nobreaklist{\@beginparpenalty=\@M}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{list}{}{}
\item{Item 1}
\begin{list}{}{\nobreaklist}
\item{Sub Item 1}
\end{list}
\end{list}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

In this example the first item of the outer list goes in the new column together with the inner list. However, if the inner list is more than a column long, this trick will fail miserably and something else must be tried.

I don't think it's possible to distinguish between "end-of-column" and "end-of-page".

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you very much, I'd have never found `\@beginparpenalty`...