# How can I ensure no page break between a description item key and the first item in an embedded itemized list?

Tags: lists, page-breaking, enumitem

If I embed an itemized list within a description list, how can I make the item label of the description stay with at least 1 or 2 items from the embedded itemized list on the same page?

I will refer to the *description item key* as the information stored within the brackets:

```
\item [key] Some descriptive value for the key.
```

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{xparse}% \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{enumitem}% \setlist
\usepackage{lipsum}% \lipsum
\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=15pt,font=\bfseries,itemindent=\dimexpr-5pt-\labelsep\relax}% Global Level 1, \dimexpr-5pt-\labelsep\relax tries to ensure nextline regardless of item key length
\NewDocumentCommand{\emptytext}{}{\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4] 

% A TeX Loop for Fun
\newcount\N
\N=0
\loop
This line takes up space\par
\advance \N by 1
\ifnum \N<6
\repeat

\begin{description}
  \item [Numbers]
    1,2,3,4,5
  \item [Letters] \emptytext
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Do not let me stand alone on a page without a context!
      \item b
      \item c
    \end{itemize}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

## Output

This is a picture of the relevant part of the output.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try the answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16136/how-to-control-column-page-breaks-in-multicols-environment-with-nested-lists)? Defining `\nobreaklist` and putting that after `\begin{description}` seems to work.

Comment: @GarethWalker I would need it to be applied only to the first or second item for aesthetics (not all items). I am not sure how to best implement that.

Comment: I don't think it does apply to all items: if you change your `\ifnum \N<6` to `\ifnum \N<4` the second list will get broken after the first item.

Comment: `\begin{itemize}[beginpenalty=10000]` will keep the first line of the first item with the heading.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is nice, but isn't there a way to make this global for all embedded lists within description lists? pseudo code: if embedded in type description list, add beginpenalty=10000

Comment: Sure read the documentation of enumitem and setup a suitable second level list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a widow-causing solution. Putting a begin penalty into the list globally as Ulrike may have suggested when she wrote, `\begin{itemize}[beginpenalty=10000]`, has an undesired side effect. Note the widow in the second list.

The solution might be to localize the addition of a beginpenalty, but I still do not know how to best implement that.

I tried with

```
\makeatletter
\ifx\@currenvir\description % attempt at checking for environment
  \setlist[itemize,1]{beginpenalty=10000}
\fi
\makeatother
```

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{xparse}% \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{enumitem}% \setlist
\usepackage{lipsum}% \lipsum
\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=15pt,font=\bfseries,itemindent=\dimexpr-5pt-\labelsep\relax}% Global Level 1, \dimexpr-5pt-\labelsep\relax tries to ensure nextline regardless of item key length

%\makeatletter
%\ifx\@currenvir\description % attempt at checking for environment
  \setlist[itemize,1]{beginpenalty=10000}
%\fi
%\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\emptytext}{}{\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

% A TeX Loop for Fun
\newcount\N
\N=0
\loop
This line takes up space\par
\advance \N by 1
\ifnum \N<6
\repeat
%
\makeatletter
\begin{description}
  \item [Numbers]
    1,2,3,4,5, \@currenvir
  \item [Letters] \emptytext
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Do not let me stand alone on a page without a context!
      \item b
      \item c
    \end{itemize}
\end{description}
\makeatother
%
\lipsum[1-4]

newline here

newline here

newline here

newline here, notice item 1 stays with this line due to beginpenalty=10000
\begin{itemize}
\item hello
\item goodbye, thanks, now I am a widow
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```